# JGit commiting with past (old) dates to local repository

Tags: java, git, datetime, git-commit, jgit

I would like to **commit in a specific date in the past using JGit** in Java. For example, I would like to commit to the local repository in 2023-03-01, 2023-03-02, 2023-03-03, 2023-03-04. According to many websites (including StackOverflow posts) I can achieve this by:

```
String oldDate = "2023-03-01";

PersonIdent author = new PersonIdent("X", String.valueOf(oldDate));
PersonIdent committer = new PersonIdent("X", String.valueOf(oldDate));

git.commit().setAuthor(author).setCommitter(committer).setMessage("Modified temp.txt").call();
```

However, this doesn't do what I want since the date stays the same, the actual date, coming from the system. I have checked the result using `git log` in Git Bash: (**Please check this image**)

[image]

**How can I do commits with past dates?** All help is appreciated!

Comment: Which version of JGit are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`PersonIdent`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/6.5.0.202303070854-r/org.eclipse.jgit/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/PersonIdent.html) constructor you're calling in

```
new PersonIdent("X", String.valueOf(oldDate));
```

is

> ```java
> public PersonIdent(String aName, 
>                    String aEmailAddress)
> ```
>
> Construct a new PersonIdent **with current time**.

Emphasis mine. It looks like your specifying the email address instead of the time.

To specify the time, you'll need to use one of the four other non-copy/config constructors (as of JGit 6.5.0 2023-03-07), which are

```java
public PersonIdent​(String aName,
                   String aEmailAddress,
                   Instant aWhen,
                   ZoneId zoneId)

public PersonIdent​(String aName,
                   String aEmailAddress,
                   ProposedTimestamp when)

public PersonIdent​(String aName,
                   String aEmailAddress,
                   Date aWhen,
                   TimeZone aTZ)

public PersonIdent​(String aName,
                   String aEmailAddress,
                   long aWhen,
                   int aTZ)
```

Comment: I stringly recommend that you don’t use `Date` and `TimeZone` since those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Later versions of JGit have [constructors that accept a modern `Instant` and a modern  `ZonedId`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/6.5.0.202303070854-r/org.eclipse.jgit/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/PersonIdent.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks! I updated my answer to reflect the API as of JGit 6.5.0

Comment: @Brian61354270 Working perfectly. I used `PersonIdent author_committer = new PersonIdent("X", "email", timestamp, timezoneOffset);` The timestamp was `long timestamp = dateTime.atZone(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli();` where dateTime was the `Date date = formatter.parse(oldDate);
                LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());`

Comment: That looks convoluted, @Thend. I am pretty sure that you can leave out the use of `Date`  and `DateFormat`/`SimpleDateFormat`  and simplify considerably.

Comment: `long timestamp = LocalDate.parse(oldDate)  .atStartOfDay(zone) .tiInstant()  .toEpochMilli();`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I think I'm in Central European Summer Time (CEST) +0200 UTC, so + 2 hours.

Comment: Sorry, I meant which value are you passing for time zone offset? I believe the method accepts an `int`. So is that 2 for 2 hours, or is it 7200 for 7200 seconds or 7 200 000 milliseconds, or something else? Just because I was curious how to get that value out of a modern `ZoneId` or other modern object and would like to post it as a comment if and when I find out.